# Cannot retrieve data with eloquent

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm building a search feature for my Customers table and for some reason, when I search for an entry with a specific mobile number it doesn't show up even though that data exists. I'm only experiencing this with my 'mobile' attribute while all the others are good.

This is my Customers table schema:

```
 Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('firstName')->nullable();
        $table->string('lastName');
        $table->string('companyName');
        $table->string('companyEmail')->unique();
        $table->string('branch')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('phone')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('mobile')->nullable();
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('clientType')->nullable();
        $table->string('reseller')->nullable();
        $table->string('assignedTo');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

When I try doing the same query on PHPMyAdmin, it does retrieve the data:
[image]

But while using this code, it doesn't:

```
$results = Customer::where('firstName', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-customer-fname'). '%')
        ->where('lastName', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-customer-lname'). '%')
        ->where('companyName', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-company-name'). '%')
        ->where('companyEmail', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-company-email'). '%')
        ->where('branch', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-company-branch'). '%')
        ->where('phone', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-company-phone'). '%')
        ->where('mobile', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-company-mobile'). '%')
        ->paginate(10);
```

[image: die and dumping returns null]

This is the HTML/Blade code for the mobile input field:

```
<label for="search-company-mobile">
      Mobile: 
      <input class="form-control" type="number" name="search-company-mobile">
</label>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need orWhere ... not where:

```
   $results = Customer::query();
    
    if($request->input('search-customer-fname')!=null)
    {
        $results = $results->where('firstName', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-customer-fname'). '%');
    }

    if($request->input('search-customer-lname')!=null)
    {
        $results = $results->where('lastName', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-customer-lname'). '%');
    }
     if($request->input('search-company-name')!=null)
    {
        $results = $results->where('companyName', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-company-name'). '%');
    }
       if($request->input('search-company-email')!=null)
    {
        $results = $results->where('companyEmail', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-company-email'). '%');
    }
      if($request->input('search-company-branch')!=null)
    {
        $results = $results->where('branch', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-company-branch'). '%');
    }
     if($request->input('search-company-phone')!=null)
    {
        $results = $results->where('phone', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-company-phone'). '%');
    }
      if($request->input('search-company-mobile')!=null)
    {
        $results = $results->where('mobile', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search-company-mobile'). '%');
    }

    $results=$results->paginate(10);
```

Comment: i think that too but why he and you both are searching mobile a bigint type as a string

Comment: I think mobile number should be stored as string so it can hold symbol like +

Comment: but that will increase it's searching time

Comment: if you stored mobile number as number, the number like 00969876 will be stored as 969876, you will lost 00, it is necessary cost

Comment: but the thing is the mobile number always has a certain length rule. so it can't be like 00 is starting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224029/discussion-between-gaurav-gupta-and-omr).

Comment: i tried changing the data type of mobile to string, still doesn't work. i also tried using orWhere instead but dd() still returns nothing @OMR

Comment: I forgot orWhere, please try now

Comment: it just returns all the entries instead of just the one @OMR

Comment: `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator {#327 ▼
  #total: 15
  #lastPage: 2
  #items: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1273 ▶}
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/customers/search"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▶]
}`

Comment: the one?! why it should return only one?

Comment: because only one entry has that specific mobile number, and it should be the only one that shows up @OMR

Comment: I have update my answer, see if it helps, please make sure you have string column for phone and mobile number

Comment: got it working finally, thanks very much @OMR i didn't think to use if statements instead because i felt like it was gonna be long